# dict value addition using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
initial_dict = {'a': 2, 'a': 3, 'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'b': 5, 'b': 7, 'c': 0, 'c': 67, 'c':56}
```

And I want to get:

```
target_dict = {'a': 9, 'b': 18, 'c': 123}
```

So I have to operate on `initial_dict` and the target is `target_dict`, I want to do this using list comp.

I was trying like this:

```
target_dict = {key:value + value for key, value in initial_dict.items()}
```

but I am getting an error for `value + value`. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you aware that dictionaries have **unique** keys? `{a:2,a:3,a:4,b:6,b:5,b:7,c:0,c:67,c:56}` is not a valid dictionary. And anyway your code doesn't raise any error, simply not giving the result you're expecting

Comment: @Tomerikoo: It's perfectly valid. It's just not what they expect (the last occurrence of each key determines the value, the first occurrence of each key determines the order, and all other data is discarded).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I know. Maybe the wording is wrong, of course you can assign this dictionary, it is just not the doctionary **object** you're gonna get is what I meant

Comment: Can you clarify what error you get? The expression shown does not provide the desired value, but it does not throw an error either.

Comment: @ShadowRanger It is valid code for creating a dictionary, but it is not a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

That wouldn't cause an error, it would just store the final value doubled. There is no way to compute partial values like this in a plain `dict` comprehension, because you don't have access to the `dict` as it's being constructed (it's not bound to the name until the comprehension completes), so you can't iteratively build up values as you go.

What you're trying to do is impossible, because `initial_dict= {a:2,a:3,a:4,b:6,b:5,b:7,c:0,c:67,c:56}` will actually produce a `dict` with just `{a:4,b:7,c:56}`, because `dict`s can't contain the same key twice (so the last copy of each key establishes the final value).

If you need this to work, use a sequence of pairs (which don't need to be unique), and then count them with [a `collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
 from collections import Counter

 initial_data = [(a, 2), (a, 3), (a, 4), (b, 6), ...]

 target_dict = Counter()
 for key, value in initial_data:
     target_dict[key] += value
```

Comment: Okay, but now again the same ques comes up how can you replace yours for loop with a list comprehension.

Comment: @JayKumar: You can't in the general case, as I said in my second sentence. Comprehensions (you were using a `dict` comprehension to be clear, not a `list` comprehension) can't use previously computed values to compute subsequent values; they're not available. For this specific case (where all duplicate "keys" are side by side), you could do it with help from other tools that would allow the grouping, e.g. `targetdict = {k: sum(v for _, v in grp) for k, grp in itertools.groupby(initial_data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))}`, but that's not *just* a listcomp, it's using a complex tool to assist.